# Trying to filter out elements Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, if-statement, dropdown

I'm trying to filter certain films based on selections from the below dropdowns.

```
<select id="filmDropdown">
        <option value="0">All Films</option>
        <option value="1">Film 1</option>
        <option value="2">Film 2</option>
        <option value="3">Film 3</option>
    </select>

    <select id="dateDropdown">
        <option value="All">All Dates</option>
        <option value="Mon">Mon</option>
        <option value="Tues">Tues</option>
        <option value="Wed">Wed</option>
        <option value="Thurs">Thurs</option>
        <option value="Fri">Fri</option>
        <option value="Sat">Sat</option>
        <option value="Sun">Sun</option>
    </select>

 <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="getSelectedValues()" />
```

And here's the html for the films to be selected.

```
    <div id="allFilms">

        <div id="1" class="filmTag">
            Film 1
            <p>
                Mon
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li>12:00</li>
                <li>16:00</li>
            </ul>
            <p>
                Wed
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li>19:00</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="2" class="filmTag">
            Film 2

            <p>
                Tues
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li>12:00</li>
                <li>16:00</li>
                <li>18:00</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="3" class="filmTag">
            Film 3

            <p>
                Wed
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li>12:00</li>
                <li>16:00</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I'm trying to use Javascript to hide all the films other than the one selected. This is what I'm doing but it doesn't seem to pick up the selected film and will just hide everything.

```
<script>
        function getSelectedValues() {

            var f = document.getElementById("filmDropdown");
            var selectedFilm = f.value;

            if (selectedFilm !== 0) {

                var filmClass = document.getElementsByClassName("filmTag");

                for (var i = 0; i < filmClass.length; i++) {

                    if (filmClass.id === selectedFilm) {
                        filmClass[i].style.display = "block";
                    }
                    else {
                        filmClass[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: when you select them do they accumulate in the allFilms div, how do you deselect them? because once you select them one by one after 3 times that will be it

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing your own application you might want to render the html based on a structure, like React does, for example. So you have a state where you can also represent your filters. Doing the other way around using selectors is not convenient and very confusing, you might incur in race conditions too, it doesn't worth it.

If you are doing it as external script in a page you didn't develop, something like a Grease Monkey script, then it's a different story. But if you can control how your page is rendered, you might want to change your approach.

Comment: Even if you aren't able to/don't want to introduce a rendering library or framework, the general idea of this answer is a good one. If you begin with your data in a JavaScript structure and generate HTML from it, even manually, you will end up with the naturally correct associations and will not need to reconstruct or infer their relationships by reading the DOM.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't worked with React before but I'll have a look into that.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and dirty fix, this line:

```
                    if (filmClass.id === selectedFilm) {
```

needs to be:

```
                    if (filmClass[i].id === selectedFilm) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers

Here's an alternative using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) and [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to filter the elements. Dropped the button and applied a `change` handler and simplified html.

```js
document.addEventListener("change", showSelected);

function showSelected(evt) {
  if (/dropdown/i.test(evt.target.id)) {
    const selectValues = {
      films: document.querySelector("#filmDropdown").value,
      weekday: document.querySelector("#dateDropdown").value
    };

    // (re)show all initially
    document.querySelectorAll("[data-films], [data-weekday]")
      .forEach(elem => elem.classList.remove("hide"));

    // nothing to do (selected all/all)
    if (selectValues.films < 1 && selectValues.weekday === "All") {
      return true
    }

    // css queryselectors based on values
    // i.e. all elements *not* in current selection
    const films = selectValues.films !== "0"  ?
      `[data-films]:not([data-films='Film ${selectValues.films}'])` : '';
    const weekdays = selectValues.weekday !== "All" ?
      `${films ? `, ` : ''}[data-weekday]:not([data-weekday='${
           selectValues.weekday}'])` : '';
    
    //hide all not selected elements
    document.querySelectorAll(`${films}${weekdays}`)
      .forEach(elem => elem.classList.add("hide"));
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

ul[data-films] {
  margin-left: -1rem;
}

li[data-weekday]:before {
  content: attr(data-weekday)' ';
}

ul[data-films]:before {
  content: attr(data-films);
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  margin-left: -1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  bottom: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<select id="filmDropdown">
  <option value="0">All Films</option>
  <option value="1">Film 1</option>
  <option value="2">Film 2</option>
  <option value="3">Film 3</option>
</select>

<select id="dateDropdown">
  <option value="All">All Days</option>
  <option value="Mon">Monday</option>
  <option value="Tues">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="Wed">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="Thurs">Thursday</option>
  <option value="Fri">Friday</option>
  <option value="Sat">Saturday</option>
  <option value="Sun">Sunday</option>
</select>

<ul data-films="Film 1">
  <li data-weekday="Sun">14:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Sun">16:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Sun">20:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Mon">16:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Mon">12:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Mon">16:00</li>
</ul>

<ul data-films="Film 2">
  <li data-weekday="Tues">12:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Tues">16:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Wed">12:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Wed">16:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Sun">18:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Sun">20:00</li>
</ul>

<ul data-films="Film 3">
  <li data-weekday="Tues">10:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Tues">14:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Wed">12:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Wed">16:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Fri">12:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Fri">16:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Sat">10:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Sat">16:00</li>
  <li data-weekday="Sat">17:00</li>
</ul>
```